# Java GUI проблема с отображением компонентов

Tags: java, swing, gui, jframe, jpanel

Пишу приложение, используя Java/Swing и столкнулся и проблемой:
При отображении JFrame компоненты не отображаются пока на них не наведешь мышкой. JFrame хранит в себе класс Main_GUI который наследуется от JPanel, в самом классе пока что находится кнопка и класс AllPosts_GUI котором находится JTextField.

Класс main:

```
public class Client 
{
  public static void main(String[] ar) 
   {

    JFrame jpClientGUI = new JFrame();

    jpClientGUI.setSize(800, 500);

    jpClientGUI.setTitle("Daily Poster");

    jpClientGUI.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    jpClientGUI.add(new Main_GUI());

    jpClientGUI.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Класс Main_GUI:

```
public class Main_GUI extends JPanel{
     public Main_GUI(){

     this.setBackground(new Color(100,230,240));

     GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();

     setLayout(gbl); 

    AllPosts_GUI allPosts = new AllPosts_GUI();

    add(allPosts, new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,0.0,1,
            GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START,GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
            new Insets(100,0,0,0), 0,0));   

    JButton button = new JButton("Add new Post");

    add(button, new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1,0.0,1,
            GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END,GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
            new Insets(100,150,0,0), 0,0)); 

    this.setVisible(true);

    this.validate();
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    Font font;

    g = (Graphics2D)g;

    g.setColor(new Color(200,100,100));

    font = new Font(null, Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 30);

    g.setFont(font);

    g.drawString("Welcome to \"Daily Poster\"", 220, 50);
    }
}
```

Класс AllPosts_GUI:

```
public class AllPosts_GUI extends JPanel{
    public AllPosts_GUI(){

        JTextArea ma = new JTextArea();

        ma.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        ma.setText("texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext\n"
               + "texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext\n"
               + "texttexttexttexttexttexttexttext\n");

        add(ma);

        this.setVisible(true);

        this.validate();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

    }
}
```

Во всех конструкторах специально вызывал методы this.SetVisible(true) а так же this.validate() и т.д. но это не помогло.
[image: До взамодействия]

[image: После]

Измененный код main:

```
    public static void main(String[] ar) 
{

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowMainGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowMainGUI() {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jFrame.setSize(850, 500);

    jFrame.setTitle("Daily Poster");

    jFrame.setBackground(new Color(100,230,240));

    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();

    jFrame.setLayout(gbl);

    AllPosts_GUI apg = new AllPosts_GUI();    

    jFrame.getContentPane().add(apg);

    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}   
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы переопределяете `paint()`, и поэтому прорисовка компонентов по-умолчанию не обрабатывается. Чтоб ее вызвать, в верхушку метода `paint()` добавьте `super.paint(g);`.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую вам ознакомится с основными приёмами работы со Swing. См. [Java Tutorials Code Sample – HelloWorldSwing.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java). Обратите внимание как в методе main вызывается метод формирования окна Swing.

**Обновление**

К сожалению нет времени вникнуть что у вас не так, но если код инициализации `JTextArea` перенести из класса `AllPosts_GUI` в метод `createAndShowMainGUI`, то всё работает нормально. См. код ниже. Т.к. размер комментария ограничен, кое-что пришлось сократить, оставил только новое.

```
private static void createAndShowMainGUI() {
   ... JPanel apg = new JPanel();
    apg.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    apg.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    jFrame.setContentPane(apg);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    apg.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);       
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setText("..");
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);       
    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Сделал по примеру, все отображается правильно, но мне нужно создавать свои собственные классы которые я наследую от JPanel, и вот они неправильно отображаются при добавлении их на JFrame, даже в соответствии с примером.

Comment: Покажите ваш новый код

Comment: Код измененного main привел выше. Я добавляю объект своего класса AllPost_GUI который наследует JPanel. Код AllPosts_GUI никак не изменял. Результат все тот же, что и на скринах.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так часто вызывать `validate`? И зачем его вручную вообще вызывать? Положитесь на `pack` перед вызовом `setVisible`, так же `setVisible` достаточно вызвать у фрейма, если вы конечно нигде принудительно не выставите `setVisible(false)`.